# ksqlDB generates "connect.name" element in AVRO schema and immediately kicks it out again in new version

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I'm defining a new stream with a new topic via Confluent Cloud ksqlDB GUI, automatically registering a new schema with no previous versions.

v1 of the schema looks as expected, but starts with an element
`"connect.name": "my.namespace"`, which I already don't really understand. However, there is also immediately a new version of the schema generated, which is v2 and lacks this element. How can this behaviour be explained? There are no connectors in place (which is usually the context I would expect from a `connect` element) and this has been the case for all ksqldDB-related schemas as far as I can see.

Furthermore, I could observe that `doc` fields are evolved "out" of existing AVRO schemas (in the context of ksqlDB-related schemas), which adds up to behaviour that does not meet expectations, maybe it's related because CC schema registry kicks out non-required fields by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no connectors running, then you are correct that `connect.name` should probably not be generated.

However, [ksqlDB may use Connect `Struct` types and associated `AvroData` class methods `to/fromConnectSchema` to convert between Kafka records and internal ksqlDB Row datatypes that can be queried](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/ksqldb-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/serde/avro/AvroSchemaTranslator.java), and these are used by `AvroConverter` in Connect framework to read/write to external systems, and what are generates and registers the schema you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes a lot of sense! So basically, this is a really minor "bug" (due to reuse of Connect artifacts), as it does not add anything which is required by ksqlDB itself.

Comment: There's a config value for the AvroData class to disable connect "metadata" fields, but I'm not sure if it can be defined anywhere in ksql